Unable to initialize spring boot app using jetty:run goal
I've been facing a critical issue from past one week on jetty web application deployment can any one please assist me where I'm doing the wrong stuff?
Description:

I'm building a Spring Boot (version:2.7.8) web application using JDK 17 as per client requirement.

In order to deploy the application, I'm using Jetty server with jetty-maven-plugin artifact (version 11.0.21)

I've gone through the below documentation pages to configure jetty-web.xml
https://jetty.org/docs/jetty/11/operations-guide/deploy/index.html
https://jetty.org/docs/jetty/11/programming-guide/maven-jetty/jetty-maven-plugin.html#jetty-run-goal


Now when I'm starting jetty server using clean install and jetty:run from my IDE, the server goes up but it's not detecting any WebApplicationInitializers on class path and due to this Spring Boot application is not getting initialized.
Logs:
[INFO] --- jetty-maven-plugin:11.0.21:run (default-cli) @ demo ---
[INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: demo
[INFO] Classes = /home/Downloads/demo/target/classes
[INFO] Context path = /
[INFO] Tmp directory = /home/Downloads/demo/target/tmp
[INFO] web.xml file = null
[INFO] Webapp directory = /home/Downloads/demo/src/main/webapp
[INFO] Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
[INFO] Web overrides =  none
[INFO] jetty-11.0.21; built: 2024-05-14T03:19:28.958Z; git: 996cd61addad9cb033e0e3eba6fa3f0fa3dc270d; jvm 17.0.11+9-Ubuntu-122.04.1
[INFO] Session workerName=node0
[INFO] Started o.e.j.m.p.MavenWebAppContext@2e1b374c{/bk,[file:///home/Downloads/demo/src/main/webapp/],AVAILABLE}{/home/Downloads/demo/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war}
[INFO] Started ServerConnector@4eeab3e{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8081}
[INFO] Started Server@161dd92a{STARTING}[11.0.21,sto=0] @2069ms
[INFO] Automatic redeployment disabled, see 'mvn jetty:help' for more redeployment options
pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>2.7.8</version>
       <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
       <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
       <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
       <connection/>
       <developerConnection/>
       <tag/>
       <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
       <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
          <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
             <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
                <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
          <version>1.10.0</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
          <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
          <version>2.5</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
          <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
          <optional>true</optional>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
          <version>6.1.7.Final</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>6.0.0</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>4.0.1</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
       <profile>
          <id>myTest</id>
          <activation>
          </activation>
          <properties>
             <deployable.artifactId>${project.artifactId}</deployable.artifactId>
             <ojdbc.scope>compile</ojdbc.scope>
          </properties>
          <build>
             <plugins>
                <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                   <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>3.5.0</version>
                   <executions>
                      <execution>
                         <id>enforce-configuration-setup</id>
                         <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                         </goals>
                         <configuration>
                                   <rules>
                               <requireFilesExist>
                                  <files>
                                     <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</file>
                                  </files>
                               </requireFilesExist>
                            </rules>
                         </configuration>
                      </execution>
                   </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                   <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                   <!--<version>9.4.50.v20221201</version>-->
                   <version>11.0.21</version>
                   <configuration>
                      <testClassesDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/resources</testClassesDirectory>
                      <httpConnector><port>8081</port></httpConnector>
                      <contextXml>${project.build.directory}/jetty.xml</contextXml>

                   </configuration>
                </plugin>
             </plugins>
             <resources>
                <resource>
                   <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                   <filtering>true</filtering>
                   <targetPath>${project.build.directory}</targetPath>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                   <directory>src/main/context</directory>
                   <filtering>true</filtering>
                   <targetPath>${project.build.directory}</targetPath>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                   <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                   <filtering>true</filtering>
                   <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/resources</targetPath>
                </resource>
             </resources>
          </build>
       </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
       <plugins>
          <plugin>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <configuration>
                <excludes>
                   <exclude>
                      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                   </exclude>
                </excludes>
             </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.3.0</version>
             <configuration>
                <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                   <nonFilteredFileExtension>jks</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
             </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.4.0</version>
             <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <archive>
                   <manifest>
                      <mainClass>com.example.demo.DemoApplication</mainClass>
                   </manifest>
                </archive>
             </configuration>
          </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

Jetty.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_10_0.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="contextPath">/bk</Set>
    <Set name="war">/home/Downloads/demo/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war</Set>
    <Set name="extraClasspath">/home/Downloads/demo/target/resources</Set>
</Configure>

I tried to start spring boot application by changing different jetty version compatible with JDK 17 also added web.xml to manually provide the listener class, but application initialization is not happening. I would like to initiate spring boot application by triggering jetty server.
 <listener>
     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext</listener-class>
</listener>


Mixup Spring Boot 2.X and Hibernate 6.X servlet api from jakarta and javax... also why using an old Spring Boot version...  Check: https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support

I was doing some error and trial but now kept only minimal dependencies and removed jakarta-api and Hibernate. Still facing the same issue. I'm migrating legacy spring project of 1.x version which is having some issues with 3.x so I degraded to 2.7 to check the compatibility with the existing code base.

google "Spring Boot migrate  to Spring Boot 2.x"

I recommend to read the upgrade pages of the spring boot project https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki (older versions also available) and go from 1.X to 2.0... and so on....

Also, Jetty 11 is at End of Life - https://jetty.org/download.html#what-version-do-i-use, you should be using Jetty 12 at this point in time.

Note, Jetty 11 is ONLY for jakarta.servlet (not javax.servlet).  If you still want javax.servlet support, you'll use Jetty 12 and its ee8 environment.
